# Display view with token authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, access-token, http-token-authentication

I'm trying to figure out how to display view with token authentication. 
I want to be able to make screenshot of my app without layout and with token access in http request. I don't want to login user but just access to my views. I use devise devise 3.5.10 and devise-token_authenticatable 0.4.10 with Rails 3. I can access to all the JSON request with my token authentication but can't display views if my user is not already logged in.

Answer (score 1):

In  your ApplicationController you likely have a line like

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

For the views where you want to allow access even if not logged in, you need to indicate that in the controller

```
class SpecialController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show] # or whatever actions you choose
```